# Low performance with Logstash Kafka input plugin with no-op output except metrics

Tags: logstash, apache-kafka

Test environment is as follows:

```
CPU: Intel L5640 2.26 GHz 6 cores * 2 EA
Memory: SAMSUNG PC3-10600R 4 GB * 4 EA
HDD: TOSHIBA SAS 10,000 RPM 300 GB * 6 EA

OS: CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Logstash 2.3.4
```

I used the following configuration:

```
input {
  kafka {
    zk_connect => '1.2.3.4:2181'
    topic_id => 'some-log'
    consumer_threads => 1
  }
}

filter {
  metrics {
    meter => "events"
    add_tag => "metric"
  }
}

output {
  if "metric" in [tags] {
    stdout {
      codec => line {
        format => "Count: %{[events][count]}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following result:

```
./bin/logstash -f some-log-kafka.conf                                
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 24
Pipeline main started
Count: 9614
Count: 23080
Count: 37087
Count: 50815
Count: 64517
Count: 78296
Count: 91977
Count: 105990
```

Default `flush_interval` is 5 seconds, so it looks roughly 14K per 5 seconds (2.8K per second).

With `consumer_threads` set to 10, I got the following result:

```
./bin/logstash -f impression-log-kafka.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 24
Pipeline main started
Count: 9599
Count: 23254
Count: 37253
Count: 51029
Count: 64881
Count: 78868
Count: 92663
Count: 106267
```

It looks increasing `consumer_threads` doesn't make much difference.

Based on my simple no-op consumer benchmark, I expected around 30K and at least 10K but it's just 1/10 of the expected performance.

How can I enhance its performance?

Additional comment:
With Kafka client Java library, I'm using bootstrap servers, whereas with Logstash Kafka input plugin, I'm using ZooKeeper (there's no option for bootstrap servers). I'm not sure this could lead to the huge difference.